# show only last x points on Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I have a dynamic data series like this

```
[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,2],[7,5],[8,6],[9,6],[10,6],[11,7],[12,8],[13,8],[14,9]
```

The data grows automatically, so later on, an extra data point will be added e.g. [15,13]

I have an input field in which the user can select how many points from the end he wants to show.
For example if he inputs 5, only `[10,6],[11,7],[12,8],[13,8],[14,9]` should be visible. But when the additional point is added, this should become `[11,7],[12,8],[13,8],[14,9],[15,13]` automatically.

I think I have to use `chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes()` but I don't know what to enter as parameters... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to "reapply" `setExtremes` when adding a point. The `setExtremes` function takes in these parameters ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes)):

```
setExtremes (Number min, Number max, [Boolean redraw], [Mixed animation])
```

You would have to use `min` and `max` to show the desired number of points, and have that include the last one. For example, you could do something like this:

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
var numberOfPointsToShow = 5;

// Add new random point
chart.series[0].addPoint(Math.random() * 25);

// Get index of last point
var lastPoint = chart.series[0].data.length - 1;

// Set extremes to go from "min" (based on last point) to last point
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
        lastPoint - (numberOfPointsToShow - 1), // min
        lastPoint); // max
```

See [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8r0L0p4j/) with dynamic adding of points.

Comment: Thanks for the API reference, when I googled, I only found the events.setExtremes() ...